# Loads of fonts in my dist file when I have imported 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I am creating a restaurant page using webpack.

I have added 2 fonts to the project and they work fine.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: Fairy;
    src: url(./font/Fairymuffinroundpop-1GG5e.ttf);
}

@font-face {
   font-family: Pumpkin;
   src: url(./font/PumpkinMuffin-eZlZg.ttf);
}
```

I have noticed in the dist file it is quite large and I have noticed that there are so many different fonts amongst what I have included. Is there a way of making it only run with my fonts that I have added, reducing the size of it?

[image: Dist Folder]

1. I have deleted the folder and run the project again but it loaded all the fonts again.
2. In my webpack.config.js file I have put clean: true in the output to make it clean up but it seems bulky still.

Thank you for your help!

Edited:

Here is my webpack config code:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'The Odin Project: Restaurant Page'
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
            patterns: [
                {
                    from:'node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/webfonts',
                    to: 'webfonts',
                },
            ],
        }),
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'index_bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        clean: true,
    },
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|otf)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Comment: "I have deleted the folder and run the project again" - Did you delete them from source folder as well, or only dist? Not sure what you mean by dist file, do you mean dist folder? Perhaps posting your webpack config would help.

Comment: I deleted the dist folder, src folder has a fonts folder with 2 fonts inside. I npm run build again and the image shows what was in the dist folder even though I have 2 fonts. I will add my code for webpack config now